# Excel - array function to remove spaces

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, array

I have a column of text items that can contain spaces (empty cells) in between items. On another sheet, I'm trying to use an array formula over the existing range to filter out those empty spaces.

Here is the formula:

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX(Input_Page!$C$2:$C$61,SMALL(IF(ISTEXT(Input_Page!$C$2:$C$61),ROW(Input_Page!$C$2:$C$61),""),ROW(Input_Page!C2))),"")}
```

Which was inspired by [this](https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/excel-remove-blank-cells-from-a-range) site.

In a blank workbook this works as expected, however when I try to use the formula in an existing workbook it places cells containing '0' into my array-function generated list. Both the input column and the generate output column are formatted as text. I need these empty columns to not show at all in my output region.

[input region](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0MRwe.png)
[output region](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WoVgj.png)

Any help or advice would be well appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question has been asked before, and a very detailed answer is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7068782/dynamically-remove-blanks-from-a-range-of-excel-cells).

That answer includes manual, VBA and array formula solutions.  The latter is referenced from [this website](http://www.get-digital-help.com/2007/09/16/excel-remove-blank-cells/#array), but to cut to the chase, the formula given there (slightly modified to fit your data) is:

```
=INDEX($B$1:$B$21, SMALL(IF(ISBLANK($B$1:$B$21), "", ROW($B$1:$B$21)-MIN(ROW($B$1:$B$21))+1), ROW(A1)))
```

The resulting output is shown in column C in the table below.  If you want to avoid the #NUM! errors, wrap the above formula in IFERROR(), which will give the results in Column D:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$1:$B$21, SMALL(IF(ISBLANK($B$1:$B$21), "", ROW($B$1:$B$21)-MIN(ROW($B$1:$B$21))+1), ROW(A1))),"")
```

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thank you for the information as well!

Comment: Good, glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

You could try wrapping the whole thing in an IF, funtion,

```
=IF( original formula = "", "", original formula )
```

So that if it equals blank, rather than input 0, it returns blank.

```
{=IF(IFERROR(INDEX(Input_Page!$C$2:$C$61,SMALL(IF(ISTEXT(Input_Page!$C$2:$C$61),ROW(Input_Page!$C$2:$C$61),""),ROW(Input_Page!C2))),"")="","",IFERROR(INDEX(Input_Page!$C$2:$C$61,SMALL(IF(ISTEXT(Input_Page!$C$2:$C$61),ROW(Input_Page!$C$2:$C$61),""),ROW(Input_Page!C2))),"")}
```

OR

If the actual value is not important, just the visual cue, you could create a custom number format, so that a 0 is displayed as a blank.

using `##;##;""`

[image]

Comment: This isn't a solution to the OP's real problem.  He wants to ELIMINATE the blank cells from the range in the new sheet.